# I want to list up string in python followed example

Tags: python, string, list

i want to list up string followed string.

```
STUDENT
a john
a anny
SUBJECT
b math
b physical
CLASS
a one
a two
a three
STUDENT
a pone
b julia
b sopia
CLASS
a four
a five
PROFESSOR
b uno
b sonovon
PROFESSOR
b jone
```

my goal is remove duplicate SUBJECT and join content.

SUBJECT can be random upper string.

But content must be start `a` or `b`

how can i do that?

Comment: what exactly are a and b

Comment: Can you show an example of how the output should look like?

Comment: also your objective is unclear. Refer to http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please include expected output for this input file.

Comment: @somputer did I answered to your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just group the elements in a dict using the subject as the key:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
od = OrderedDict()
with open("match.txt") as f:
    key = next(f)
    for line in f:
        if line.startswith(("a","b")):
            od.setdefault(key,[]).append(line)
        else:
            key = line
```

Output:

```
for sub,cont in od.items():
    print("{}, {}".format(sub, cont))

STUDENT
, ['a john\n', 'a anny\n', 'a pone\n', 'b julia\n', 'b sopia\n']
SUBJECT
, ['b math\n', 'b physical\n']
CLASS
, ['a one\n', 'a two\n', 'a three\n', 'a four\n', 'a five\n']
PROFESSOR
, ['b uno\n', 'b sonovon\n', 'b jone']
```

Which groups the data correctly which is what *my goal is remove duplicate SUBJECT and join content.* makes pretty obvious that is what you want.

The OrderedDict will keep order, if you want to write the updated lines to the file just reopen and  write as you iterate over .items?

```
with open("match.txt", "w") as f:
    for sub, cont in od.items():
        f.write(sub)
        f.writelines(cont)
```

New  output, joined by subject:

```
STUDENT
a john
a anny
a pone
b julia
b sopia
SUBJECT
b math
b physical
CLASS
a one
a two
a three
a four
a five
PROFESSOR
b uno
b sonovon
b jone
```

Answer (score 1):

Because the only information about SUBJECTS is that they are upper strings, you can split your file using `isupper()` predicate this way:

```py
def split_string(file_name):
    list_ = [ x for x in open(file_).read().splitlines()]
    for i,j in enumerate(list_):
        if not (j.isupper() and list_[i + 1].isupper()):
            print j 
split(file_name)
```

Note: I suppose here that your string is stored in a file

Comment: how does your code group the content? why are you using a list comp. calling read and then splitting when  `open(file_).readlines()` would do the same thing? So apart from being unpythonic it is also wrong.

Comment: want to explain why you downvoted my correct answer?

Comment: mine is correct to, anyway! I undown-devoted your answer.. have a nice day

Comment: I think you need to try your code! You basically print every line in the file, you could make it `for line in f:print(line)` and it would be the same